# How to update pub package webdev for flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

when I try to "serve" my flutter web app
I'm getting this error:

> This version of webdev does not support the `build_daemon` protocol
>   used by your version of `build_runner`. A newer version of webdev is
>   available which supports your version of the `build_daemon`. Please
>   update.

how do I update **webdev** ?
"pub global" seems to offer only "activate"/ "deactivate"
and "pub upgrade" is only looking into the pubspec.yaml file

any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh... I just run "pub global deactivate " and then "pub global activate ".
Anyway I opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/issues/2332) suggesting to add the feature "update".
I hope this easy solution might help you, 
feel free to follow up the issue.

Comment: You can always just re-run `pub global activate` to get the latest version. No need to `deactivate` first!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `build_daemon: ^1.0.0` in `dev_dependencies:` of .yaml file fix my error

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a global version, but use a per-project version.

To ensure running *webdev* on your project always works, include the version of *webdev* it requires in the *pubspec.yaml* file:

```
dev_dependencies:
  webdev: ^2.7.9
  ...
```

And run it using:

```bash
$ dart run webdev ...
```

This ensures the correct version of *webdev* is installed when *dart pub get* is run, and that particular version is used for the project.

This avoids having to update the global version when things change. Running `dart pub global deactivate webdev` and `dart pub global activate webdev` is unnecessary work.

Globals are bad. Using "*dart pub global activate ...*" installs only one version of *webdev*, which may become out-of-date with your project (as you've discovered). Or you might have multiple Dart projects, and they require different versions of *webdev*. The above approach uses a per-project version of *webdev*, ensuring it is always the correct version for the project.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem now when I followed this tutorial https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-create-and-deploy-a-website-from-scratch-4a026ebd6c, but I didn't get pass the error by running flutter pub global activate.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the following command to update webdev

```bash
flutter pub global run webdev deactivate
```

and then

```bash
flutter pub global run webdev activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i configured in my computer

> - run: pub get
> - run: webdev serve

```
dev_dependencies:
  build_daemon: ^1.0.0
  build_runner: ^1.4.0
  build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0
```

Wish this will fix your issues.